# Can't get PrettyFaces running with Quarkus & Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, quarkus, prettyfaces

I'm experimenting with Quarkus + Myfaces/Primefaces based on this repo https://github.com/apache/myfaces/tree/master/extensions/quarkus/showcase.

Here I'm trying to include Prettyfaces to get nicer URLs. More specifically I'm trying to use OCPSOFT [Rewrite](https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite) by following this guide
https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/configuration/annotations/index.asciidoc by using annotation.

Seems to me that, when using annotations, I just need to add dependency into pom and annotate a page like this: @Join(path="/welcome", to="/demo/index.xhtml") . I did both, can see

> "RewritePhaseListener starting up"

in console but URL /welcome is not working. Anyone having working example of [Rewrite](https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite) in Quarkus?

Comment: Is this in native or JVM mode? And what do you mean by "is not working"? 404 error?

Comment: JVM, it doesn't work in dev mode already. And 'doesn't work' simply  means that http://localhost:8080/welcome is not available ...

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that Rewrite will just work out of the box without a special quarkus module.

Comment: You are probably right, just courious if someone resolved this.

Comment: I would submit an issue to the Rewrite URL team.